# How to Drop a Table In Synapse SQL Database Serverless Pool Builtin

Tags: azure-synapse

I am trying the following code to drop a table in Azure Synapse

drop dbo.tablename

drop tablename

[image]

But I keep on getting errors such as:

```
Unknown object type 'ts_originationopportunity' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.
```

Or

```
Unknown object type 'dbo' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.
```

[image]

Can someone let me know what is the correct syntax to drop a table in Azure Synapse Serverless Builtin Pool please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, Synapse has two types of SQL. One is dedicated SQL Pool and another one is Serverless SQL Pool.

Dedicated SQL Pools will contain tables & external tables. Where as serverless SQL Pool has only external tables.

> To drop table use syntax as `DROP TABLE table_name`. To drop external
> table use syntax as `DROP EXTERNAL TABLE table_name`

Below are screenshots of same for better understanding.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me  .

```
use [your DatabaseName] 
GO 
drop EXTERNAL table schemaname.tablename
```